# Terraform ec2 module with conditional ebs device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ebs, availability-zone

We have a requirement to create a ec2 module and use it to create a ec2 instances (1 or more) + ebs device/ebs volume and use the same ec2 module to create ec2 (1 or more) w/o any ebs volumes.

I tried it via conditional (count) but hitting all sorts of errors. Help!

Comment: Can you provide more info to the issue like the error you've gotten

Comment: I would really recommend using a ternary in `count` instead of relying on the casting of booleans into numbers, especially since both are not supported types until 0.12 and I think that behavior is changing too.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to conditionally create a resource, you can use a ternary to calculate the `count` parameter.

A few notes:

- When using `count`, the `aws_instance.example`, `aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-1`, and `aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-2` resources will be arrays.
- When attaching the EBS volumes to the instances, since the `aws_volume_attachment` resources have a `count`, you can think of them as iterating the arrays to attach the volume to the EC2 instances.
- You can use `count.index` to extract the correct item from the array of the EC2 instances and the two EBS volume resources. For each value of count, the block is executed once.

```
variable "create_ebs" {
  default = false
}

variable "instance_count" {
  default = "1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count         = "${var.instance_count}"
  ami           = "ami-1"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = "subnet-1" #need to have more than one subnet
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs-volume-1" {
  count             = "${var.create_ebs ? var.instance_count : 0}"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a" #use az based on the subnet
  size              = 10
  type              = "standard"
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs-volume-2" {
  count             = "${var.create_ebs ? var.instance_count : 0}"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  size              = 10
  type              = "gp2"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs-volume-1-attachment" {
  count         = "${var.create_ebs ? var.instance_count : 0}"
  device_name   = "/dev/sdf${count.index}"
  volume_id     = "${element(aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-1.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_id   = "${element(aws_instance.example.*.id, count.index)}"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs-volume-2-attachment" {
  count         = "${var.create_ebs ? var.instance_count : 0}"
  device_name   = "/dev/sdg${count.index}"
  volume_id     = "${element(aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-2.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_id   = "${element(aws_instance.example.*.id, count.index)}"
}
```

For more info on `count.index` you can search for it on the [Terraform interpolation page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html)